# Short file name question?

Tags: filenames

Im trying to add some short file names to a Wise installer to fix validation errors, which is simple for the most part. However if I have the following two files:

LongFile1.dll
LongFile1.EN.dll

Should these be:

LongFi~1.dll and
LongFi~2.dll ?   Or do I have to do anything special becuase of the .EN.dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are named LONGFI~1.DLL and LONGFI~2.DLL (all letters capitalized in 8.3 file format).  Which is which is determined by the order they are created.

In a cmd window you can type dir /x to view the short file names as well.